# Circular Directory Error and smaller than usual hard drives

Tags: centos6

The OS is CentOS 6 with Parallels Plesk Panel 10 (64-bit).

Our df -h looks like this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             4.0G  822M  3.2G  21% /
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  4.0G  1.3G  2.6G  33% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  4.0G  2.6G  1.2G  70% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home 4.0G  136M  3.7G   4% /home
none                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /tmp
```

Until I deleted a massive file, `/dev/mapper/vg00-var` was at 100%. I've also rebooted the server. There appears to be two problems:

1. The Drive sizes look very small (4G) where it should be substantially larger (500G - 1TB)
2. Upon going a `du -sh *` inside the `/var` directory, this is the following output:

.

```
[root@xxx var]# du -sh *
39M  cache
8.0K db
8.0K empty
4.0K games
2.0G lib
4.0K local
24K  lock
17M  log
16K  lost+found
0    mail
du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  `named/chroot/var/named'
156K    named
4.0K    nis
4.0K    opt
8.0K    parallels
4.0K    preserve
104K    qmail
152K    run
216K    spool
4.0K    tmp
474M    www
4.0K    yp
```

I'm assuming this is the cause of why the website on the server is doing odd things. Can you advise a way forward or things to try?

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, I'd start by getting off that system immediately and forcing a FULL fsck of all the filesystems.  At the point, you can assess the damage after that point.

Comment: This looks like it may be a known CentOS bug - http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3736 do I still need to do a full FSCK?

Comment: I'd definitely say say YES.  It can never hurt to have the file structure clean.